# Using base use case as include use case

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

[image: use case]

I am trying to draw a use case diagram for navigation. However, I am not sure if it is correct since the 'call out address' base use case is being used as included use case.
Any comments on the above diagram please?

Comment: Naming an `Actor` _Actor_ is a bit silly. Like calling a screen actor _screen actor_ instead of _Inspector Colombo_  or whatever...

Comment: If you learned that at a university: look for another course (or uni). If it's from some online lesson: try to get your money back. It's really frightening how many questions are here which have not got the point with use cases. I had a similar issue 20 years ago when self-teaching UML. But seeing that still being a frequent issue makes me shiver :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a use case diagram. Your bubbles contain Actions being part if some Activity carried out by a use case. A use case shows added value an actors gets from the system under considertion. Please start at square one!

I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about use case modelling. The best read you can get on that topic.